# Can't kill processes of a user

Tags: process, kill, killall

One of the users of our server managed to hang his xRDP connection somehow. Now he can't connect any longer. Each time he tries to connect, he gets a blank black screen. I figured this is due to some error in the X11rdp process he was running, so I tried to kill the process using `killall X11rdp`, `kill -KILL`, `kill -s SIGCHLD`, `kill -9`... Then I tried killing all the processes of that user using `pkill -u`. But they won't die. None of them. I literally have no idea what is happening. Any ideas?

P.S.

Of course, I executed all these commands as root.

Comment: Possibly, your proc has a child proc, keeping it allive. Try `pkill -P <pid>`

Comment: @JacobVlijm I've tried that, too. The process survives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this on the processes the user has.  If it has problems on a particular process it'll show you the parent process.  You can then run the script on the parent process.

I haven't found a process that it won't subsequently kill yet.

**Create the bash script with:**

```
$ gedit killprocess.sh
```

**The script:**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! "$1" ]]
then
    echo "Parameter error... exiting..."
    exit
fi
process=$1

count=0
results=0
while [[ $(ps h -fp $process) ]]
do

    kill -9 $process
    str1=$(ps h -fp $process|awk '{print "["$2"]["$3"]"}')
    results=$?
    echo -ne "[$str1]Response:$results..."

    ret2=$(ps -ef | egrep "\s$process\s" | awk '$2 == '$process'{print "["$2"]["$3"]"}')    

    if [ ! "$ret2" ]
    then
        break
    fi       

    if [[ -f stop ]]
    then
        exit
    fi
    if [[ $((count++)) -gt 5 ]]
    then
        echo -ne "\nGiving up... exiting...\n"
        exit
    fi  

    sleep 20
done

echo -ne "\n"
```

**Make it executable:**

```
$ chmod +x killprocess.sh
```

**Run the script:**

```
$ sudo ./killprocess.sh
```